# How to filter data table column for null or white space

Tags: c#, filter, datatable

In order to filter data table column for null or white space I used this filter but it dosn't work

```
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = 
string.Format("[{0}] ='%{1}%'(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dt.Columns[int.Parse(comboBox8.Text) - 1].ColumnName.ToString())),true);
```

Comment: Why not dt = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<object>[0] != null).CopyToDataTable();

Comment: sory it dosn't work  i need to edit the filter above to filter null or white space  for column name dt.Columns[int.Parse(comboBox8.Text) - 1

Comment: You can use column name instead of index : dt = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => (x.Field<object>[comboBox8.Text] != null) 
|| !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Field<string>([comboBox8.Text])).CopyToDataTable();

Comment: sorry it dosnt work

Answer (score 0):

i solve it by :
 1- use this fun

```
public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string value)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(value[i]))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

then  i use this code for specific column in data grid view :
 if((function.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataGridView3.Rows[j].Cells[int.Parse(comboBox8.Text) - 1].Value.ToString()) == true))
dataGridView3.Rows[j].Cells[int.Parse(comboBox8.Text) - 1].Value = "Empty";

then i use this filter :
  dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("[{0}] not LIKE '%{1}%'", dt.Columns[int.Parse(comboBox8.Text) - 1].ColumnName, "Empty");